# Powershell PSSessionStateBroken error

Tags: powershell

I use the following powershell command to RDP to a server and start a service. It was working fine until last week before we cut over the server to a different data center.

```
 Invoke-Command -ComputerName itbldw13 {Start-Service -Name bamboo-remote-agent}
```

The error that i get after the cut over is

```
 Connecting to remote server itbldw13 failed with the following error message : The client cannot connect to the destination specified in the request.  
+ CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (itbldw13:String) [], PSRemotingTrans   portException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotConnect,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Could someone help me fix this error please

Comment: `portException` : a new firewall on your way, maybe ?

Comment: Thanks, checked that and that doesn't seem to be the issue.